# What is the name of GCM Server library to add to build.gradle to get latest Message class?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I need to access the latest implementation of the Message class as maintained here: https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/master/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.java

I tried to add the dependency 'com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.0' to my build.gradle in the android project, but it does not have this implementation of the Message class (for e.g., the priority method is missing).

What is the right name / version of the gcm-server library that I should add to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may be facing this issue, here's what I found out:

The Message class in the jcenter repository is not the latest (i.e. does not have the priority-related implementation) in this library: https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.gcm%3Agcm-server/view#files/com/google/gcm/gcm-server/1.0.0

But, the same library com.google.gcm:gcm-server:1.0.0 in mavenCentral repository has the Message class with the priority implementation.

So, I resolved this issue by switching to using mavenCentral repository instead of jcenter in my project build.gradle file.

Comment: Odd.. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.google.gcm:v1.0.0'
    }

Comment: Hi @SQLiteNoob , I tried this. But am getting the error: Failed to resolve: com.github.google.gcm:v1.0.0 . What am I missing?